# iOS app with dynamic library injection

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-injection

I would like to implement Dynamic Library Injection. Below is what I do but without success:

**1. create injection.dylib by compile injection.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <objc/objc.h> 
id evil_say(id self, SEL op) {

       printf("Bawhawhawhaw! I'm Evil!\n");
       FILE *f= fopen("/tmp/sample.txt","w");
       fprintf(f, "OKOK");
       fclose(f);
       return self; 
} 

static void __attribute__((constructor)) initialize(void) {

       FILE *f= fopen("/tmp/sample.txt2","w");
       fprintf(f, "OKOK");
       fclose(f);   
       class_replaceMethod( objc_getClass("SaySomething"), sel_registerName("say:"), evil_say, "@:" ); 
}
```

**2. sign lib**

ldid -S injection.dylib

**3. Write sample HelloWorld iOS that:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SaySomething : NSObject - (void) say: (NSString *) phrase; @end
@implementation SaySomething
- (void) say: (NSString *) phrase {
    printf("%s\n", [ phrase UTF8String ]); }
@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

 (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    SaySomething *saySomething = [ [ SaySomething alloc ] init ];

    [ saySomething say: @"Hello, world!" ];

...
```

**4. Build and run app by xcode7 --> HelloWorld app is installed and run**

**5. Copy injection.dylib into HelloWorld.app folder using iFunBox**

**6. Modify Info.plist in HelloWorld.app folder by adding Environment Variables (Dictionary) with 1 item:**

```
  key=DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

  value=/var/lib/mobile/<xxx-xxx....>/HelloWorld.app/injection.dylib
```

**7. Open HelloWorld app on iPhone**

But I could not find any sample.txt/sample.txt2 in /tmp folder of iPhone. It mean library not being loaded.

Could anybody tell me where is my fault?